# Django url patterns for different currencies

Tags: django, caching, seo, django-templates, django-urls

I am building a site in english and simply want to offer a small subset of currencies.  For SEO and caching I am planning to develop the following url structure with the prices being displayed in the relevant currencies.

Home(s)

- site.com/
- site.com/au/
- site.com/us/
- ...

Categories Index Pages

- site.com/categories/
- site.com/au/categories/
- site.com/us/categories/
- ...

Product Index Pages

- site.com/categories/category1/
- site.com/au/categories/category1/
- site.com/us/categories/category1/
- ...

Product Pages

- site.com/categories/category1/product-1/
- site.com/au/categories/category1/product-1/
- site.com/us/categories/category1/product-1/
- ...

This is my attempted url.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.homeCurrency, {'cur_slug': '' }, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<cur_slug>[:au|nz|us|eu|ca|uk]+)/$', views.homeCurrency, name='home'),
    url(r'^categories/', include('parts.urls', namespace="parts")),
    url(r'^(?P<cur_slug>[:au|nz|us|eu|ca|uk]+)/bike-parts/', include('parts.urls', namespace="parts")),
)
```

This is the sort of dynamic url I need in my base.html

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
```

My problem is two fold (I think)
Firstly, I can't allow for the default case i.e. site.com(/) in the url pattern so that there is a common url name that can be used dynamically throughout each version of the site.

Secondly, even ignoring the default case, I am getting the following error:

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    site.com/au/
Django Version: 1.5.4
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is my first project in Django. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is with your regex. `[]` means character class, i.e. `[a|bc]` would match `a`, `|`, `b` or `c` but never `bc`.

Hence, your regex should be using groups `()`:

```
url(r'^(?P<cur_slug>au|nz|us|eu|ca|uk)/$', views.homeCurrency, name='home'),
```

If you're not 100% confident with regex, you should have a look into the excellent [surlex](http://codysoyland.com/2009/sep/6/introduction-surlex/) library, which provides a neat little DSL for writing URL patterns.

```
from surlex.dj import surl

// a macro for valid currencies
surlex.register_macro('$', r'au|nz|us|eu|ca|uk')

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    // macros are only used in match groups (surrounded with `<>`)
    surl(r'<cur_slug:$>/$', views.homeCurrency, name='home'),
    surl(r'<cur_slug:$>/bike-parts/$', include('parts.urls', namespace="parts")),
)
```

regarding your choice of "dynamic url", why not instead base your url roots on locale, and choose the correct currency based on locale. [REF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#url-internationalization)

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I initially looked at the locale functionality but thought it might have been overkill.  How would I use locale functionality to go about creating the url patterns for the desired url structures above and what would be the benefits? Thanks again

Comment: Also, the docs say this: "i18n_patterns() is only allowed in your root URLconf. Using it within an included URLconf will throw an ImproperlyConfigured exception.".  Will this cause any issues given that I include the parts.urls?

Comment: The benefits of using the built-in i18n framework is that you can use it to offer localised content in addition to localised pricing. Also, large django projects like `django-cms` integrate with it naturally as well.